# Get value from php function to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am stuck with getting an array from php function located in another file to a javascript. I used the below code but nothing is happening.

PHP code:

```
$sprd_array;
$spread = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $spread =(int) ($value->ask*100000) - ($value->bid * 100000);
        $spread =(float) $spread / 10000;
        $spread = round( $spread, 5, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
        $sprd_array[] = $spread;
    }
    for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($sprd_array); $i++){
        //echo "spread: " . $sprd_array[$i] . "<br />";
    }
    return $sprd_array;
}
```

I want to get the array in another javascript file.

javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'jsondecode.php',
    complete: function (response) {
        alert("done");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
return false;
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Your PHP code has **OUTPUT** your value. a `return` doesn't output anything. `echo json_encode($sprd_array)` would do the trick. echoing out the array directly would just produce the literal word `Array`.

Comment: would you please explain with a code. I didn't understand you very well sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: its not a duplicate. I checked the link. It is different

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
$.ajax({
      url:'jsondecode.php',
      dataType : json,
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data); // This is the data you want.
      },
      error: function () {
          alert("error");
      }
  });
```

Comment: nothing happened. should I add any code in the php file ? like if($_POST...etc ?? I put alert on success and error and am not getting any message

Comment: Have you included jquery file?

Comment: You Need to include the jquery source file; you can download it here : http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Use the code before doing this ajax, `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, use the function `json_encode()` to encode your objects / arrays to JSON Format. Note that setting the second argument to true will keep associative array indeces.

Also, your JavaScript code is not alright. You need to use `success:` instead of `complete:`. Then, you can easily convert the string back into an object using `JSON.parse(yourJSONString);`.

Answer (score 0):

In php change "`return $sprd_array;`" to:

```
echo json_encode($sprd_array);
```

Comment: I did it but the alert is not showing. It means its stuck in a place I can't find.

Comment: There is no such function is JavaScript. You need to use `JSON.parse(jsonString)` as described in my answer.

Comment: should I include a JQuery file ?

Comment: @Tacticus I forgot - json_decode is just function in js that I defined and always use, of course it should do what you described, sorry.

Comment: @Tacticus using JSON.parse didn't solve the problem. nothing is happening.

Comment: make sure you echo in php, and not return, if it is ajax!